# Wave ripple effect?

Tags: xna, c#, hlsl

I've been working on a tower-defense game for some time now, and so far I am really satisfied with the results. However, there's one thing I'd like to add.

I've seen a video of GeoDefense for Windows Phone 7 here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhPr4A4LRPQ

Notice how (when a unit gets killed or a projectile hits a unit), the background ripples in some kind of wave effect.

How can I make an equivalent? I'm thinking that I somehow need to do it in the vertex shader, with a quad made of many vertices.

What's your call?

**Edit** It is important to note that my XNA game is not made for Windows phone, but for Windows PCs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that XNA on Windows Phone doesn't have custom shader support - so you *can't* write a vertex shader or pixel shader. However, you can use a trick described by [Catalin Zima](http://www.amusedsloth.com/2011/01/screen-space-deformations-in-xna-for-windows-phone-7/) that deforms a vertex grid to achieve the same effect.

If you are not targetting Windows Phone 7, you can use a trick that I [described on my blog](http://jonathan.dickinsons.co.za/blog/2011/01/versatile-distortions-in-xna/). Copying the relevant bits in:

These distortions require 2 images. Firstly you need the entire scene as a render target (i.e. Texture2D) as well as the distortion render target. Typically you would use a particle system to fill the distortion render target; using special distortion sprites (example below).

Each color component in the distortion target (and distortion sprites) represents the following:

- **R**: dx: X offset – f(x)=2x-1 mapping ([0.0f, 1.0f] to [-1.0f, 1.0f]).
- **G**: dy: Y offset – f(x)=2x-1 mapping.
- **B**: m: Z strength – f(x)=x mapping.

A good example of a sprite that would be used for a ripple would be:

[image: Ripple Sprite]

Determining the outcome of a ripple is as simple as adding the waves together (keeping in mind the mapping you need to perform first to [-1.0f, 1.0f]); because waves in reality are also additive this *just works* - you will get very good approximations of real waves.

Once you have the two render targets you can use the following shader:

```
Texture InputTexture; // The distortion map.
Texture LastTexture; // The actual rendered scene.

sampler inputTexture = sampler_state
{
    texture = <InputTexture>;
    magFilter = POINT;
    minFilter = POINT;
    mipFilter = POINT;
};

sampler lastTexture = sampler_state
{
    texture = <LastTexture>;
    magFilter = LINEAR;
    minFilter = LINEAR;
    mipFilter = LINEAR;
    addressU = CLAMP;
    addressV = CLAMP;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float2 TexCoords : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 Distort (VS_OUTPUT Input)
{
    float4 color1;
    float4 color2;
    float2 coords;
    float mul;

    coords = Input.TexCoords;
    color1 = tex2D(inputTexture, coords);

    // 0.1 seems to work nicely.
    mul = (color1.b * 0.1);

    coords.x += (color1.r * mul) - mul / 2;
    coords.y += (color1.g * mul) - mul / 2;

    color2 = tex2D(lastTexture, coords);

    return color2;
}

float4 RunEffects (VS_OUTPUT Input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color;

    color = Distort(Input);

    return color;
}

technique Main
{
    pass P0
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 RunEffects();
    }
}
```

This is the final effect:

[image: Ripple Effect]

This technique should also work for 3D games; although you might have to dedicate more thought to the particle shader and the distortion shader.

Comment: I am not making the game for Windows Phone. I've updated my question.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen I lifted some content off my blog and put it in the answer, hopefully it gives you a good starting point.

Comment: The phone example is nice and is exactly what I am trying to do. Unfortunately, I want the effect to move with the world, and not be based on screen coordinates. Is that possible?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen It's definitely possible, but it will be incredibly expensive - in which case I recommend you go for my solution. I will mail you the code if I can find it; as long as you promise to not use any of my artwork :).

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson Could you please provide us with updated XNA 4 code?

Comment: Great trick! :)

Comment: @AmirRezaei depends on how much time I have to port it - game dev is a hobby for me; so I usually don't have the time.

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson I can help porting the code if you send me the the old source code.

Comment: @AmirRezaei right, I'll scratch around for it when I get home.

Comment: @AmirRezaei [get it while it's hot](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=a73a98a284a7340b&resid=A73A98A284A7340B!216&parid=A73A98A284A7340B!107)! Consider the code public domain, but attribution would be nice.